# Get pictures from a given directory using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-metro, winjs

I am using JavaScript to develop a Windows 8 application. I need to get all the pictures (path of each and every picture) present in a given directory. How would I do this?

I have the following:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var page = WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/html/scenario3.html", {
        ready: function (element, options) {
            document.getElementById("folder").addEventListener("click", pickFolder, false);
        }
    });

    function pickFolder() {
        // Clean scenario output
        WinJS.log && WinJS.log("", "sample", "status");

        // Verify that we are currently not snapped, or that we can 
        // unsnap to open the picker
        var currentState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value;
        if (currentState === Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState.snapped && !Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.tryUnsnap()) {
            // Fail silently if we can't unsnap
            return;
        }

        // Create the picker object and set options
        var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker;
        folderPicker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.desktop;
        // Users expect to have a filtered view of their folders depending on the scenario.
        // For example, when choosing a documents folder, restrict the filetypes to documents for your application.
        folderPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll(["*"]);
        //folderPicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll([".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg"]);

        folderPicker.pickSingleFolderAsync().then(function (folder) {
            if (folder) {
                // Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder (including sub-folder contents)
                // Cache folder so the contents can be accessed at a later time
                Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.futureAccessList.addOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);

                var pictures = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.folder;
                pictures.getFilesAsync().done(function (images) {
                    console.log(images.length + " images found.");
                    WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Total Images: " + images.length, "sample", "status");
                });


            } else {
                // The picker was dismissed with no selected file
                WinJS.log && WinJS.log("Operation cancelled.", "sample", "status");
            }

        });
    }
})();
```

If I use the Above code it gives following error:

`Unable to get property 'getFilesAsync' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks daniel, 
Actually this is first time i am developing win 8 app using javascript, In c# i have idea that files could be obtained by Directory.GetFiles ,

Comment: I know How to pick directory, But do not know how to filter all pictures present in that given directory

Comment: Unless I'm missing some important aspect of Windows 8, I don't think JavaScript has access to the file-system.

Comment: I am trying and now i can access to the given directory, I guess i am very close to the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to load pictures from the Pictures Library, you first need to check that this capability is enabled within the Capabilities tab inside the `package.appxmanifest` file of your project.

Once enabled, you can refer to this library with the following:

```
// 'pictures' is a reference to our Pictures Library
var pictures = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary;
```

Microsoft made the decision that any operation taking more than 50 milliseconds would need to be asynhronous, therefore to get the images from this library we must the following async method, and handle the results when the promise is resolved:

```
// Get a list of files ('images') within our Pictures Library
pictures.getFilesAsync().done(function( images ) {
    console.log( images.length + " images found." );
});
```

From here you could iterate over the images found and handle them as you like.

For more information, check out the [`Window.Storage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227346.aspx) namespace.

Additionally, you may find the [File access sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597/view/SourceCode) to be helpful as well.

#### Update

From your updated code I can see that you're permitting the user to select a folder of their choosing. With this you'd need to set the `fileTypeFiltering` and then pull the images once the `pickSingleFolderAsync` promise resolves:

```
// Prompt user to select a folder
var picker = Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();

// Which file types will we be showing?
picker.fileTypeFilter.append(".jpg");

// Grab the selected folder, reference as 'folder'
picker.pickSingleFolderAsync().then(function (folder) {
    // Get files within selected folder as 'files'
    folder.getFilesAsync().then(function (files) {
        // Output number of files found
        console.log(files.length + " files found.");
    });
});
```

Comment: It give an error for me: 
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'getFilesAsync' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @mshahbazm Double-check your code. You may also post an update here if you like.

Comment: `folder` is not a member of `knownFolders`. Also, where do you declare `folderPicker`?

Comment: you code works great when i use Picture library, But when i replace picture library with folder that user had picked then error occurs

Comment: if selected folder is not a member function, then how to access its contents

Comment: Thanks for your time, you solved my problem, very very thanks